Understanding the Application of Fourier Transform and ODE in a Specific Context
I am currently studying a mathematical concept and I have come across an equation from this post that I am having trouble understanding. Some key information from @Liding Yao is as follows:
$$u(y)=e^{-y\sqrt{-\Delta_x}}f$$
In particular, we have:
$$u(y_1+y_2)=e^{-y_1\sqrt{-\Delta_x}}u(y_2)$$
So, we can derive:
$$u_y(y)=-\sqrt{-\Delta_x}e^{-y\sqrt{-\Delta_x}}f$$
$$u_y(0)=-\sqrt{-\Delta}f$$
$$u_y(y)=e^{-y\sqrt{-\Delta_x}}(u_y(0))$$
The formula $e^{-y\sqrt{-\Delta}}$ can be derived using ODE on Fourier transform. Let's assume $f\in L^2$ for simplicity. If we take Fourier transform only on the x variable we have $(\partial_{yy}^2-\xi^2)\widehat{u(y)}(\xi)=0$ with IVC $\widehat{u(0)}(\xi)=\hat f(\xi)$. Solving the ODE we get $\widehat{u(y)}(\xi)=a(\xi)e^{y|\xi|}+b(\xi)e^{-y|\xi|}$. If $a\neq0$ then $u(y)$ cannot be in $L^2$, that is why only $e^{-y|\xi|}$ is left with $b=\hat f$. Taking Fourier inverse we get $e^{-y\sqrt{-\Delta}}$.
I am confused about the details of how to apply the Fourier transform and ODE in this context. I am not entirely familiar with the results in Fourier Analysis and ODE. Could anyone provide a more detailed explanation or point me to some resources where I can learn more about this?
Thank you in advance for your help!
